# Что использовать/делать/учить?

Tags: php

Я только начал изучать php, для того чтобы лучше освоить язык начал делать учебный проект. Я делаю веб-сайт со статьями, который берёт их из БД. Написал главную страницу, отображение статей по отдельной категории, а также отдельную страницу для статьи, прикреплю скрины: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу реализовать подключение к сайту по авторизации, а также самому написать авторизацию через социальные сети. У авторизованных пользователей могут быть разные права на сайте, типа как на SO, при разных достижениях, уровень прав увеличивается.
Авторизованные пользователи с нужными правами могут создавать статьи на сайте, редактировать их. Подскажите, что мне нужно изучить, чтобы такое написать?
Как мне это сделать более-менее удобно, чтобы не теряться в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую Вам пользоваться фрейморками, в Вашем случае laravel или yii2
 Они в разы упростят Вам работу с веб
 Если же Вы хотите сделать всё самостоятельно на pure, то Вам необходимо создать страницу авторизации с записью в БД. 
 Пример можете посмотреть [Тут](https://otus.ru/nest/post/882/) 
  Для авторизации через социальные сети Вам понадобятся API запросы к этим сетям. Пример [Тут](https://evilcoder.ru/vk-api-avtorizatsiya-dlya-sayta/)
Далее, в php, при получении достижений, (Будь, то редакция данных или ещё что) вы проставляете в БД триггер доступа (Новая колонка в таблице, к примеру, *права*)

И в нужных Вам местах, где это необходимо, всегда ставить проверку. 
 Если права в БД этого пользователя равны такому-то значению, то отображать данные, если нет, то нет.

Больше информации Вы сможете найти в интернете по запросу Типы пользователей на PHP

Comment: Предупреждение читателям этого ответа: по первой ссылке - устаревший и нерабочий код, содержащий не одну, не две, а *множество* хрестоматийных уязвимостей.